# Перенаправить на другую страницу при удачном ответе с сервера в React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

В приложении react-a на странице делается запрос добавления новости, и если ответ с сервера положительный, нужно перенаправить на страницу со всеми новостями. Не могу понять как это сделать, React только учу)

```
        const response = await request('post', '/api/new/add', formData)
        const data = response.data
        if (data.status === 201) {
            #Тут хотелось бы что то вставить, и перенаправлять на другую страницу
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Подробнее о хуке [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory).

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();
const response = await request('post', '/api/new/add', formData)
const data = response.data
if (data.status === 201) {
    history.push('/страница');
}
```